# What is causing iml's FeatureEffects to throw an error on a caret trained model?

Tags: r, iml, r-ale

I'm trying to use the [iml](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iml/iml.pdf) package in TIBCO's R (TERR 6.1.0) and I am getting an error from `FeatureEffects$new` that I cannot make sense of. I am training a random forest using `caret`, then I am squeezing the model into a `Predictor` object as required by `iml`. And finally I'm trying to compute `FeatureEffects` and it throws this error:

*Error in diag(dists.cumulated) : Can only replace the diagonal of a matrix*

I have a short code snippet from the documentation below and my version of it beneath. The only difference is that I am using `caret` to train my model but this is explicitly mentioned as supported in the documentation. Does anyone have experience with `caret` and `iml` and has a clue what is going on? Needless to say that the code from the documentation throws no such error...

Code snippet from `iml` documentation:

```
library("rpart")
data("Boston", package = "MASS")
rf <- rpart(medv ~ ., data = Boston)
# Squeeze the model into a Predictor object
mod <- Predictor$new(rf, data = Boston)
# Compute the accumulated local effects for all features
eff <- FeatureEffects$new(mod, method="ale")
```

Adopted code snippet using my `caret` based model:

```
# Train a random forest using caret:
mtry <- 1:max(1,floor(ncol(Boston)*0.9))
tunegrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = mtry)
cntrl<-trainControl(method = "oob", number=5, search='grid', verboseIter=TRUE, savePredictions=TRUE)
rf.model <- caret::train(Boston[, names(Boston) != "medv", drop=FALSE], Boston[, names(Boston) == "medv"], method="rf", ntree=250, metric="RMSE", trControl=cntrl, tuneGrid=tunegrid, nodesize=floor(nrow(Boston)*0.8), importance=TRUE)
# Squeeze the model into a Predictor object
mod <- Predictor$new(rf.model, data=Boston)
# Compute ale effects for all features
eff <- FeatureEffects$new(mod, method="ale")
```

Comment: Just a thought: could it be that if the train/test split in my data set results in features in the train data set which only have a single constant value/category could that be the issue?

Comment: Your code is not fully reproducible. I get "Error: object 'input.train' not found".

Comment: Uups, sorry, copy&paste error. I will correct it but during testing the corrected code I found the answer myself (incompatible R engine). I will post it as an answer right after making the corrections to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs only when using TIBCO's Enterprise Runtime for R (TERR) or as it is recently called "Spotfire Enterprise Runtime for R version 6.1.0". I did not pay attention when posting this question and accidentally used TERR inside RStudio w/o noticing it. Apologies!

When testing the corrections I used open source R 4.3.0 and it is running just fine. I will leave the question in here for the benefit of other TERR users but I will correct the question to not say R but TERR.